# Брутфорс и потоки

Tags: алгоритм, многопоточность

Не могу понять как работает многопоточный брутфорс. Допустим есть словарь для перебора:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

Каким образом этот словарь распределяется по потокам? По половине? То есть если я запускаю 2 потока, в первом потоке будет `aaa, bbb`, во-втором — `ccc, ddd`?!

Comment: Да как угодно. может четные одному потоку нечетные другому. Может работа некими блоками выдается. А может и как вы предположили.

Comment: как делается более правильно? при большом количестве потоков (50-100)

Comment: Нет "более правильного".

Comment: Допустим есть словарь из 15 слов, хочу запустить в 4 потока. Как их правильно распределить?

Comment: Надо понимать, что просто увеличение потоков - не особо помогает. Брут зависит от алгоритма того, что брутится. Чаще всего используется хотя бы "встречный" брут, когда с начала и с конца сразу. Бывают уязвимости алгоритмов, когда какие то "слова" имеют большую вероятность чем другие. Нет общих рекомендаций.

Comment: есть такая штука - producer-consumer. В этом случае producer - это код, который генерирует последовательность слов (или читает с файла). А Consumer - это потоки, которые проверяют. В результате consumer  поток запрашивает у producer потока какое-то кол-во слов и проверяет их.